# Problem with Google indexing URLs in my XML SiteMap

Tags: google, seo, sitemap

My XML sitemap has a lot of links - for example:

> nanoc.gigfa.com/post.php?id=1
>   nanoc.gigfa.com/post.php?id=2
>   nanoc.gigfa.com/post.php?id=3
>   nanoc.gigfa.com/post.php?id=4
>   nanoc.gigfa.com/post.php?id=5

I've added my sitemap via Google Webmaster Tools (my site map -> www.nanoc.gigfa.com/sitemap.php), but Google has only added this page -  nanoc.gigfa.com/post.php?id=1 - from 171 pages.

This is the Google Tools result when i submit my sitemap:

```
    Sitemap     Status  Type    Downloaded  URLs submitted  URLs in web index
/sitemap.php        OK  Sitemap     Sep 2, 2011     171             1
```

Why has Google added only 1 page in web index?

Answer (score 3):

There's possibly a number of reasons:

1. Does the sitemap validate (as XML)?
2. Is Google showing errors in the WebMasterTools console for this sitemap?
3. When did you submit the SiteMap? Some lower-ranked sites can take days/weeks to crawl/index
4. **ARE THE CONTENTS OF YOUR SITE WORTH INDEXING?** <- main problem

Many of the URLs I visited on your site are empty pages - e.g: www.nanoc.gigfa.com/index.php?par_lev=25 - why should Google index this?

Comment: 1- is ok 2- no error 3- one week later i index that 4-many urls is empty but many url consider content, why google not index that pages?

Comment: why google not index this pages? http://www.nanoc.gigfa.com/post.php?id=3 http://www.nanoc.gigfa.com/post.php?id=2 ?

Comment: please see reason #4. If none of those page have back-links (external to your site), and your site isn't well back-linked and Google doesn't deem the content to be of any value then there's no reason for it to be indexed. I ask you - why *should* Google index your page?